# Protect my Expressjs app routes from requests outside my android app

Tags: android, node.js, express

I have a full application API written in node.js with Express.. Now, the API should be only accessed from my Android application, how can I protect the node app from outside requests?

If I use some kind of a password protection, I'll have to write that password in my android app and since the application is available to everyone, the password can be easily found.. What is the solution to this kind of situations?

Comment: You can use device id compulsory..if it is null dont call API.OK

Answer (score 0):

Web based security can be a bit tricky sometimes, but if you have an app you could use a token-base approach.

When your application starts, it can request a token from your API, which then must be present in all other requests to your API.

Did a quick search for this kind of thing and came upon this page, which might be worth a look: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/architecting-a-restful-node-js-app/

Comment: Thanks for answering.. The thing is that anyone can request the token and then use that token to send requests from outside the app.. For example, I am the hacker, I'll try to decompile the apk from android, find the way that the application is requesting the token and request it myself..

Comment: Yes, but that is true for everything... :)

But you can construct the token in a specific way that gives you some more security, for example:

Give it out to a authenticated user in your app, for a certain IP and with a specific lifetime, to name a few of the options you have.